# Calculations with a function (Error: object not found)

Tags: r

I have an data frame with many parameters. To make it easy i made an example with 3 columns. The first one consists of the units, the second one consists of the given parameters and the third one consists of the calculated numbers. What i want is the following:
- a suitable way to store the units and numbers
- a function that makes tables with changing parameters (like the second example with windspeed 3 and 4 m/s). Would be cool to add a function that changes the parameter windspeed AND density at the same time.
Now i have some code that works. Unfortunately i have to process it line by line. For 20 different wind speeds it is a lot of unnecessary work i think.

```
aa <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(100),nrow=6,ncol=3))

aa$V1 <- c("v (m/s)","Cd ()", "d (m)", "A (m^2)", "N/(W*L)", "V(m/s)")

aa$V2 <- c("1",  # v 
    "2", # Cd
    "3",     # d
    "4",   # MW/km^2
    "5",    # Height
    "6"   # coefficient
)

aa$V3[1] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[4,2]) ^ 2)
aa$V3[2] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[1,2]) + as.numeric(aa[2,2])) 
aa$V3[3] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[1,2]) * as.numeric(aa[2,2])) 
aa$V3[4] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[1,2]) + as.numeric(aa[2,2]) +    
as.numeric(aa[3,2])) 
aa$V3[5] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[2,2]) + as.numeric(aa[2,3]))   
aa$V3[6] <- as.numeric(as.numeric(aa[1,3]) + as.numeric(aa[2,3]))
```

What i already have to get what i want is this:

```
speed_vector <- c("w_sp_3" = 3, "w_sp_4" = 4)
make_speed <- function(x)  
{

V1 <- c("v (m/s)","density (kg/m^3)","Cd ()", "d (m)", "A (m^2)", "N/(W*L)",  
"V(m/s)")

V2 <- c(speed_vector[x],  # v 
      "1",      # density
      "2", # Cd
      "3",     # d
      "4",   # MW/km^2
      "5",    # Height
      "6"   # coefficient
      )

V3 <- c(as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[4]) ^ 2),
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) * as.numeric(V2[2])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V2[3])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V3[2])),   
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V3[1]) + as.numeric(V3[2])))


zz <- data.frame(V1,V2,V3) 
return(zz) 
}

w_speed_3 <- make_speed("w_sp_3")
w_speed_4 <- make_speed("w_sp_4")
```

Now i get the following:

> `"Error in make_speed("w_sp_3") : object 'V3' not found".`

Please help me to find the mistake.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do so I can't help much, but in the creation of `V3` in your `make_speed` function you are referring to `V3` in the last two lines. `V3` has not been defined yet, and so it cannot be found and you get an error.

Comment: Yes, in your assignment of V3, you're referencing V3.

Comment: @OriolMirosa: thanks for your answer. I just try to make calculations with changing parameters and store this in a list, data.frame or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by "with changing parameters"? Are you saying the column V3 in your data frame should be calculated based on the values that you put in V2? If each row in V3 is a different calculation, you should put each one of those in a column, and then each row would have the different operations for the same entry. Is that what you want?

Comment: @OriolMirosa: Partly Correct. Most of column V3 should be calculated based on the values from V2. But the last rows of V3 should be calculated based on values of V3 (calculated before based on V2). This is one part of my problem. The second part is, that i want to change 2 parameters (which changes most of the resulting values). I tried to do this with the function "make speed".

Comment: No ideas how i can store my calculations?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within the following syntax:

```
V3 <- c(as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[4]) ^ 2),
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) * as.numeric(V2[2])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V2[3])), 
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V3[2])),   
      as.numeric(as.numeric(V3[1]) + as.numeric(V3[2])))
```

You're defining the object V3 as a vector, but in the final two lines of that vector, you are referencing V3 itself, before V3 exists. In other words, you are trying to define V3 using an object that has not yet been defined (V3).

Edit:

```
make_speed <- function(v){

    V1 <- c("v (m/s)","density (kg/m^3)","Cd ()", "d (m)", "A (m^2)", "N/(W*L)",  
    "V(m/s)")

    V2 <- c(v,  # velocity 
          "1",      # density
          "2", # Cd
          "3",     # d
          "4",   # MW/km^2
          "5",    # Height
          "6"   # coefficient
          )

    V3 <- c(as.numeric(V2[4]) ^ 2,
            as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]), 
            as.numeric(V2[1]) * as.numeric(V2[2]), 
            as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V2[3]), 
            as.numeric(V2[2]) + as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]),
            as.numeric(V2[4]) ^ 2 + as.numeric(V2[1]) + as.numeric(V2[2]),
            NA)  # The other vectors have 7 items, V3 only has 6 in your example

    return(data.frame(V1,V2,V3))
}

w_speed_3 <- make_speed(v = 3)
w_speed_4 <- make_speed(v = 4)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already had that idea but I really don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I mean if u have a look on the first example, it works. I just want to put the first example into a function and add 2 changing parameters (e.g."w_speed_3" and "density_5")

Comment: Sorry, if i could not clearly describe my problem. Please have a look on the comments above. They might give you an idea what i want.

Comment: No ideas how i can store my calculations?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a working version of your function. Hope this solves your problem.